# BlockingQueue.peekWait()

Tags: java, queue, blocking

I have a situation where I would like a method `peekWait` on `BlockingQueue`.  I would describe this method as

> retrieves but not remove the head of the queue, waiting if necessary
>   until an element becomes available

I cannot see a corresponding method on BlockingQueue, LinkedBlockingQueue.  Does this exist or can I do this somehow?  I considered doing `poll()` + `addFirst()` but the queue may fill up in between leaving me stuck.

Comment: why not create your own custom method ?

Comment: I can't modify LinkedBlockingQueue.  Extending it doesn't give the necessary access to the internal locks it uses.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't look like you can implement `peekWait` in any nice way. Using reflection to access the condition and the locks would make it very fragile.

Comment: I don't think it's doable without really ugly hacks. What are trying to achieve (=what is concrete use case)?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the call to `BlockingQueue#peek()` in a `Callable`, execute it and wait on `Future<T>.get(long, TimeUnit)`:

```
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

scheduler.schedule(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    String e = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    System.out.println("adding = " + e);
    queue.add(e);
  }
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>()
{
  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception
  {
    String result = null;
    while ((result = queue.peek()) == null)
    {
      Thread.sleep(100L);
    }
    return result;
  }
};

String peeked = null;
try
{
  peeked = executor.submit(task).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  System.out.println("this should never be printed");
  queue.poll();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
  System.out.println("null: peeked = " + peeked);
  e.printStackTrace();
}

try
{
  peeked = executor.submit(task).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  System.out.println("not null: peeked = " + peeked);
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("should not throw an exception");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though perhaps "call peek() in a loop with a sleep()" would be simpler :)

Comment: simpler but inefficient